# Delphi OnClick Problem with Multiple Units

Tags: delphi, event-handling, onclick

When I make a dynamic component from unit I have no problem creating the OnClick event.
When I make a dynamic component from **unit 2** I am unable to access the OnClick event.

```
unit Unit1  
type  
    TForm1 = class(TForm)  
      procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);  
    private  
      { Private declarations }  
    public  
      Procedure ClickBtn1(Sender: TObject);  
    end;  

var  
    Form1: TForm1;  
    MyBtn1: TButton;  
implementation  

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }
uses Unit2;

procedure TForm1.ClickBtn1;  
begin  
    MyBtn1.Caption := 'OK';  
    MakeBtn2;  
end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
    MyBtn1 := TButton.Create(Self);  
    MyBtn1.Parent := Form1;  
    MyBtn1.Name := 'Btn1';  
    MyBtn1.Left := 50;  
    MyBtn1.Top := 100;  
    MyBtn1.Caption := 'Click Me';  
    MyBtn1.OnClick := ClickBtn1;  
end;  


end.



unit Unit2;

interface

uses
    Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
    Dialogs, StdCtrls;

procedure MakeBtn2;  
procedure ClickBtn2;      
var  
    MyBtn2: TButton;  

implementation

Uses Unit1;

procedure MakeBtn2;  
begin  
    MyBtn2 := TButton.Create(Form1);  
    MyBtn2.Parent := Form1;  
    MyBtn2.Name := 'Btn2';  
    MyBtn2.Left := 250;  
    MyBtn2.Top := 100;  
    MyBtn2.Caption := 'Click Me';  
    MyBtn2.OnClick := ClickBtn2;    //Compiler ERROR
end;  

procedure ClickBtn2;  
begin  
    MyBtn1.Caption := 'OK';  
end;  
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this article "[Creating A Component at Runtime](http://www.delphicorner.f9.co.uk/articles/comps4.htm)"

Quote:

> I want to create a button in code, put
>   it on a form and attach a procedure to
>   its click event. How can I get the
>   click event linked to a predefined
>   procedure name from code? I assume the
>   IDE linking in the object browser is
>   key to the answer, but I want to do
>   this at run time, not in development.
>
> First of all, you can assign any
>   object's method to another method as
>   long as it has the same form. Look at
>   the code below:

```
{This method is from another button that when pressed will create
 the new button.}
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  btnRunTime : TButton;
begin
  btnRunTime := TButton.Create(form1);
  with btnRunTime do begin
    Visible := true;
    Top := 64;
    Left := 200;
    Width := 75;
    Caption := 'Press Me';
    Name := 'MyNewButton';
    Parent := Form1;
    OnClick := ClickMe;
  end;
end;

{This is the method that gets assigned to the new button's OnClick method}
procedure TForm1.ClickMe(Sender : TObject);
begin
  with (Sender as TButton) do
    ShowMessage('You clicked me');
end;
```

> As you can see, I created a new method
>   called ClickMe, which was declared in
>   the private section of Form1:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm
  ...
  ...
  private
    procedure ClickMe(Sender : TObject);
  published
  end;
```

For other examples and explanations see also the following:

- [Understanding the Sender parameter in Delphi Event Handlers](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/sender.htm)
- [How to set a component's default event handler](http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=17)
- [Delphi 6 Component Structure](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26862&seqNum=4&rll=1)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the first example works?  Neither of these should compile.

An OnClick handler is a TNotifyEvent, which is defined as

```
procedure(Sender: TObject) of object;
```

That means that it has to be a method of an object (such as a form), and the method signature has to be a procedure that takes a single TObject parameter.  Your procedure MakeBtn2 isn't an object method, and neither of them takes Sender: TObject.

Comment: What would be the best way to acheive what I want?

Comment: Declare a method on your form with the correct signature, and put the code you're trying to execute in there.